# Route pattern cannot reference variable more than once

Tags: symfony

**Settings:**

- Symfony 3
- To stay simple, I will refer to a simple `AppBundle`, with `Entity1` and `Entity2` as entities.
- There are no specific parameter per entity, just an `id`.
- `Entity2` is a child of `Entity1`, which mean that in the SQL diagram, Entity2 have a foreign key `entity1_id`.

**Summary:**

I'm trying to build the following route:

- `/entity1/{id}/entity2/{id}/show`

Where the first `{id}` is the id of `Entity1`, and the second of `Entity2`.

**My .yml files:**

*entity1.yml*

```
entity1_index:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Entity1:index" }
    methods: GET

entity1_show:
    path: /{id}/show
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Entity1:show" }
    methods: GET

entity1_new:
    path: /new
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Entity1:new" }
    methods: [GET, POST]

entity1_edit:
    path: /{id}/edit
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Entity1:edit" }
    methods: [GET, POST]

entity1_delete:
    path: /{id}/delete
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Entity1:delete" }
    methods: DELETE

# ENTITY2
entity2:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/entity2.yml"
    prefix: /{id}/entity2
```

*entity2.yml*

```
 entity2_index:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Entity2:index" }
    methods: GET

entity2_show:
    path: /{id}/show
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Entity2:show" }
    methods: GET

entity2_new:
    path: /new
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Entity2:new" }
    methods: [GET, POST]

entity2_edit:
    path: /{id}/edit
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Entity2:edit" }
    methods: [GET, POST]

entity2_delete:
    path: /{id}/delete
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Entity2:delete" }
    methods: DELETE
```

**Problem:**

Route pattern cannot reference variable more than once, which is here my problem.

I don't know what to do so that Symfony can differentiate each `{id}`.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but why use `{id}` twice? Instead of `/entity1/{id1}/entity2/{id2}/show`... Then the controller can handle the two different ids. Or is there something you haven't told us?

Comment: Hewwo Alvin~ It's not stupid at all, guess it's my fault to not have specified it clearly... You quite point the problem right... Why not doing that... Because I don't know how to do that... ^^ If by any chance, you know how to rename `{id}`to `{id1}` and `{id2}`, please share your knowledge with me on a new comment... :)

Comment: @Preciel You shouldn't use [salutations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/323179) in your posts. You can look at the link for more information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hewwo~

Thanks for the details Alvin.
I haven't tried annotation routing yet, I'm not familiar with it yet.
I will keep that post marked, as of now, I already made too many routes to switch to annotation routing.
But I will try for my next project... ;)

Meanwhile, I figured out how to solve my problem.
Thus, here are the details.

**Settings:** Same as the first post.

**Solution:**

**Rename route variables:**

*• entity1.yml*

```
entity1_index:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Entity1:index" }
    methods: GET

entity1_show:
    path: /{idEntity1}/show
defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Entity1:show" }
methods: GET

entity1_new:
    path: /new
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Entity1:new" }
    methods: [GET, POST]

entity1_edit:
    path: /{idEntity1}/edit
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Entity1:edit" }
    methods: [GET, POST]

entity1_delete:
path: /{idEntity1}/delete
defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Entity1:delete" }
methods: DELETE

# ENTITY2
entity2:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/entity2.yml"
    prefix: /{idEntity1}/entity2
```

*• entity2.yml*

```
entity2_index:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Entity2:index" }
    methods: GET

entity2_show:
    path: /{idEntity2}/show
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Entity2:show" }
    methods: GET

entity2_new:
    path: /new
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Entity2:new" }
    methods: [GET, POST]

entity2_edit:
    path: /{idEntity2}/edit
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Entity2:edit" }
    methods: [GET, POST]

entity2_delete:
    path: /{idEntity2}/delete
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Entity2:delete" }
    methods: DELETE
```

**Rename `$id` in entities:**

*• Entity1.php*

`private $id;` to `private $idEntity1;`

*• Entity2.php

`private $id;` to `private $idEntity2;`

**Edit the controllers:**

`[...]` indicate that code was skipped, thus not edited.

*• Entity1Controller.php*

`newAction` changes:

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('entity1_show', array('id' => $entity1->getId()));
```

to

```
return $this->redirectToRoute('entity1_show', array('idEntity1' => $entity1->getId()));
```

For each `redirectToRoute`we find, we will rename the `id` variable to match our route/entity variable.

---

`editAction` changes:

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Entity1 $entity1)
{
    [...]
    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        [...]
        return $this->redirectToRoute('entity1_edit', array('idEntity1' => $entity1->getId()));
    }
    [...]
}
```

---

*• Entity2Controller.php:*

In every function, we will add our parent entity as variable.
If not done, our routes won't works

`indexAction` changes:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    [...]
}
```

to

```
public function indexAction(Entity1 $entity1)
{
    [...]
    return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(
        'entity1' => $entity1,
        'entity2s' => $entity2s,
    ));
}
```

---

`newAction` changes:

```
public function newAction(Request $request, Entity1 $entity1)
{
    [...]
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        [...]
        return $this->redirectToRoute('entity2_show', array(
            'idEntity1'=>$entity1->getId(),
            'idEntity2'=>$entity2->getId()
        ));
    }
    return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(
        'entity1' => $entity1,
        'entity2' => $entity2,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

---

`showAction` changes:

```
public function showAction(Entity1 $entity1, Entity2 $entity2)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($entity1, $entity2);
    return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:show.html.twig', array(
        'entity1' => $entity1,
        'entity2' => $entity2,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

---

`editAction`changes

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Entity1 $entity1, Entity2 $entity2)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($entity1, $entity2);
    [...]
    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        [...]
        return $this->redirectToRoute('entity2_edit', array(
            'idEntity1'=>$idEntity1,
            'idEntity2'=>$entity2->getId()
        ));
    }
    return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:edit.html.twig', array(
        'entity1' => $entity1,
        'entity2' => $entity2,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

---

`deleteAction` changes:

```
public function deleteAction(Request $request, Entity1 $entity1, Entity2 $entity2)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($idEntity1, $entity2);
    [...]
    return $this->redirectToRoute('entity2_index', array('idEntity1' => $entity1->getId()));
}
```

---

`createDeleteForm`changes

```
private function createDeleteForm(Entity1 $entity1, Entity2 $entity2)
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('entity2_delete', array('idEntity1' => $entity1->getId(), 'idEntity2' => $entity2->getId())))
        ->setMethod('DELETE')
        ->getForm()
    ;
}
```

This sum up all the changes needed...
As long as you can replace code through a whole project, it's quite fast to do...

Thank you Alvin and david for your replies.
While I didn't ended up using them, I'm sure they will be usefull in the future.
Be it for me or for someone else... :)

This topic is now solved... ^^

Comment: Are you serious? Better nobody see that shit in future. You can use everywhere `{id}` only if you have two entities ids as parameters use different param name.

Comment: @malcolm : Well, indeed, it could have been improved... While your somewhat agressive answer didn't help me, because it wasn't clear, it at least made me search a bit futher... I do hope this solution suit your better... And you should consider some more gentle answers... Some of us are old... We love some respect... And above all... We're not here to fight... Being knowledgeable doesn't mean you can be rude... ;)

Answer (score 1):

I suggestion you use Route annotations instead. I personally find it much easier to use.

For example, you could do something like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/editEntity1/{id1}/entity2/{id2}",
 *  defaults={"id1" = 0,"id2" = 0},
 *  name="editEntity1Route")
 */
public function editEntity1Action($id1, $id2, Request $request){
    ...
    // Now you can use both id variables like so:
    $eName1 = $id1->getName();
    $eName2 = $id2->getName();
    ...
}
```

I renamed the route 'editEntity1Route' because it explicitly tells you what is does. In this case Edit Enitity 1. Then in you controller you would have other routes for "showEntity1", "newEntity1" etc...

In another controller the easy way to redirect to the above route is like so:

```
...
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('e1')
    ->from('AppBundle:Entity1', 'e1')
    ->where('e1.e1_name = :e1_name')    // Example
    ->setParameter('e1_name', "sample name");
$entity1 = $qb->getQuery()->setMaxResults(1)->getOneOrNullResult();
...
$entity2 = $qb->getQuery()->setMaxResults(1)->getOneOrNullResult();

return $this->redirectToRoute('editEntity1Route', array(
        'id1' => $entity1->getId(),
        'id2' => $entity2->getId(),
));
```

Also, in Twig it is very easy to setup a link to the route:

```
<a href="{{ path('editEntity1Route',
         {'id1':entity1.getId, 'id2':entity2.getId}) }}">Edit Entity1</a>
```

In the above twig file, this presumes from your controller you've passed in the variables 'entity1' and 'entity2'.

I think this might give you some ideas on how to achieve this if you use routing annotation. You could still use routes in the Yaml files, I just find it more obvious using routing annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your *entity1.yml*

```
entity2:
resource: "@SalonBundle/Resources/config/dashboard/soushall.yml"
prefix: /{id}/soushall
```

Try remove these `{id}`, so the route becomes `/entity1/entity2/{id}/show`.

Now, your `{id}` is the id from Entity2. Since Entity2 have a foreign key `entity1_id` that linked to the id from Entity2, it is enough for the route to just read one id from Entity2.

Comment: While it's indeed a solution (which I hadn't thought of), I have to keep the id of each entity in the url.
I still have a lot of entity to imbricate like that, and they all needs the same pattern.

If really nothing is possible, then I will use your solution, but if I can avoid it, it would be great. :)